# Can't target this child

Tags: html, css

I want to target the class `has-translucent-status-bar` which is located inside another class named `platform-ios`

For that I've tried to do:

```
.platform-ios > .has-translucent-status-bar
```

So far, I was not lucky enough to do so, here is a screenshot of the code:

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that actual code that we can copy and paste it much better than a screen shot. Luckily for you in this instance the issue is easy to spot.

Comment: @JonP for that reason, I made the screenshot ;)

Comment: Do you have any other selectors targeting `.has-translucent-status-bar`? If so you need  to come up with a more "specific" rule. You shold research CSS specificity if this is the case. Also be aware of selectors that apear after your selector in the code base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go with:

```
.platform-ios .has-translucent-status-bar
```

The [child selector/combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) you used is for direct children:

> The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those
>   elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of
>   elements matched by the first.

In your specific case, the only, or one among the others, direct child of `.platform-ios` is `ion-app` element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn't work

Comment: You will have to inspect in browser and see which style overrides it. The selector I used in this answer is correct, so either add more specificity (as `.platform-ios > ion-app > ion-nav .has-translucent-status-bar`) or add `!important` (in case you don't wanna bother with it).